# Distributions over continuous distributions

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes

I know a few stochastic processes that are described as 'distributions over distributions'. For example, the [Dirichlet process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#Applications_of_the_Dirichlet_process) draws discrete distributions from a default model [(see e.g., p3 of these notes)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1516/L101/clark_lecs/notes_5.pdf) .

The discrete distributions could be made continuous by assuming some kinds of kernels. E.g., if you have a discrete distribution with a probability $p_i$ associated to a variable $x_i$, you could make a continuous distribution from Gaussian kernels,
$$
p(x) = \sum_i p_i \cdot g(x | \mu = x_i, \sigma^2 = 1)
$$
where $g$ is a Gaussian.

Furthermore, although the discrete distributions from a Dirichlet process are a 'small' set of the continuous ones, it can be argued that they are a 'large' set in the weak or pointwise sense [(see e.g., p4 of these notes)](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~ywteh/research/npbayes/dp.pdf). Thus, a Dirichlet process could be used to relax a parametric model in a non-parametric way.

*However, are there any distributions over continuous distributions?* That is, is there e.g. a stochastic process like the Dirichlet one that covers a set of continuous distributions in a strong rather than weak sense? Is there e.g. a meaningful continuum limit of the Dirichlet process that could be used for this purpose? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: *Every* Bayesian model concerns a "distribution of distributions," whence any Bayesian model of a continuous distribution--such as the textbook Normal distribution--will serve to answer your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don’t see how a Normal distribution could be an answer to my question.

Comment: Let $X$ be a random variable with a Normal distribution and let $Y$ be a Normal distribution of unit variance and mean $X$: That's what might be understood by a "distribution of distributions."  If that's not your understanding, then please edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: I see, but the example is obviously parametric and only covers the set of Gaussian distributions of unit variance. Let me clarify

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this edit?  Since you are referring to *two* levels of distribution--a prior distribution that governs the generation of posterior distributions--which of these is supposed to be "non-parametric"?  I'm unsure even what you might mean by "non-parametrically." The problem is that the language of your post seems to be all over the place in referring to "distributions," "kernels," and a "stochastic process."  It is very hard to determine what subject it's trying to focus on or what it's trying to ask.

Comment: ok, I hope it is clearer now, please reopen.

Comment: whuber: that's certainly a distribution of distributions, but its support is very small. In Ferguson's 1973 "A Bayesian Analysis of Some Nonparametric Problems", he lists 2 desiderata at the very beginning. the first one is "The support of the distribution should be large -- with respect to some suitable topology on the space of probability distributions on the sample space."

Comment: I've only just started looking around with a similar question, and this (22-year-old) paper (https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/petrone1997.pdf) comments at the end "Unfortunately, in the Bayesian literature there are not many proposals of priors which are well suited for nonparametric analysis (i.e., which have "large" support on the class of d.f.'s on the sample space) and which select continuous distributions."